# How to create a string literal based on generic character type in c++20?

Tags: c++, generics, c++20, string-literals, wchar-t

Given the following test case

```cpp
int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    {
        constexpr wchar_t const* v = gstring<"hello world", wchar_t>();
        std::wcout << v << std::endl;
        std::wcout << std::wcslen(v) << std::endl;
    }
    {
        constexpr char const* v = gstring<L"world hello", char>();
        std::wcout << v <<  std::endl;
        std::wcout << std::strlen(v) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output should be

```
hello world
11
world hello
11
```

This is useful when the character type is passed in as a type parameter.  For example

```cpp
template <typename TChar>
void AddFoo(std::basic_string<TChar> & s){
    s.Append( gstring<"foo", TChar>() );
}
```

Comment: Why are you specifying a `char` string when a `wchar_t` string is wanted? Or a `wchar_t` string when a `char` string is wanted? These require data conversions to avoid data loss, and those type of conversions can't be done at compile-time for non-ASCII characters. What is the actual goal here?

Comment: You do know about problems converting wide character strings to (ascii) strings right? It is already tough at runtime, let alone at compile time.

Comment: My comment at the end made clear it's not a good idea going from wide to ASCII..itw as just a test case for the code

Comment: I believe that char can be mapped 1 to 1 to wchar but obviously not the other way round. It would certainly be possible to insert any consteval conversion routine to specialise. My main itch to scratch here was figuring out how to perform the conversiin from one literal type to another at compile time and leave no mess behind. For production and special requirements one would have to look carefully. I admit very little familiarity with encoding issues.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename Char, unsigned N>
struct Capture {
    Char string_[N + 1]{};

    template <typename TChar>
    consteval Capture(TChar const* string) {
        for (unsigned index = 0; index < N+1; ++index) {
            string_[index] = string[index];
        }
    }

    template <typename TChar> 
    consteval auto As() const{
        return Capture<TChar, N>(string_);
    }
};

template <typename TChar, unsigned N>
Capture(TChar const (&)[N]) -> Capture<TChar, N - 1>;

template <Capture string, typename Char, auto cast = string.template As<Char>()>
consteval auto gstring() {
    return cast.string_;
}
```

It requires a two stage process. The first step is to capture the `const char *` using an implicit conversion to type `Capture`. The second step is to call the `As` method on `Capture` to convert the buffer to the new type. All this is done `consteval` and via template parameters to ensure that the literal object is global.

The gstring method can return the inner final buffer as `cast.string_` because `cast` is a template parameter and thus a compile time constant.

See the solution on GodBolt
https://godbolt.org/z/GaTnh69cM

*Note*: The conversion should really only be used from `char -> char` or `char -> wchar_t`. Obviously not all values in `wchar` have values in `char`